# How to play sound effects in Vue 3 app with Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am attempting to setup a basic button click in Vue 3 Composition API to trigger a sound effect. Currently, my setup function includes an mp3 sound effect imported from the assets folder then passed into a ref method with an HTMLAudioElement type, then assigned to a const called "play". After adding the "play" constant to the return, I then added "play" to a click handler in the button. I'm not getting errors in the console, but the button is still not triggering the sound effect. How can I go about configuring the setup function and button to trigger the sound effect? Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div div class="flex justify-center">
    <button @click="play">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue' 
import { trumpetSfx } from '../assets/demo_src_assets_fanfare.mp3'

export default {
  name: 'Button',
  components: {},
  setup() {
    const play = ref<HTMLAudioElement>(trumpetSfx);

    return { play }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That code is horribly wrong, I'm afraid. `play` is a ref holding the sound file data. Setting the type argument will not magically turn it into an `HTMLAudioElement`. You can use the `Audio` constructor, as shown in the answer by @MaverickFabora. This creates an actual `HTMLAudioElement`, which has a `play()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Audio` API directly from javascript:

```js
import trumpetSfx from '../assets/demo_src_assets_fanfare.mp3'

...
setup() {
    const audio = new Audio(trumpetSfx);
    
    function play() {
        audio.play()
    }

    return { play }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const trumpetSfx = require("../assets/demo_src_assets_fanfare.mp3");

export default {
  setup() {
      const audio = new Audio(trumpetSfx);
    
      const handleClick = () => {
        audio.play()
      }

      return { audio, handleClick }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Maverick Fabroa I tried your way but the import still didn't work. After some additional tinkering, I ended up using a require method to pass in the mp3 clip from assets and that seemed to work.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.